# Changing drop down submenu positioning CSS only

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I'm trying to use a checkbox dropdown style menu to house all my site content on one page.  The basic idea is that the dropdown submenus will contain the  content related to it's label (about, links, etc) for a light site. I'm trying to achieve this all with CSS only.

The first submenu (ABOUT) displays nicely, but the submenu that follows it aligns all the content with it's related label, which makes sense obviously.

However, the effect I would like to achieve is have each submenu's positioning take up the entire width of the viewport and always align with the left of the screen, as it does when ABOUT is clicked.

Here is my codepen.

https://codepen.io/maxineheadroom/pen/gxPzpE

```css
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

q {
  quotes: \201C \201D \2018 \2019;
}

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -.25em;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: .35em .625em .75em;
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button,
html input[type=button],

/* 1 */
input[type=reset],
input[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],
input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

body,
figure {
  margin: 0;
}

legend,
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header,
footer,
section {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

header {
  /*     background-color: blue;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 2000px;
}

.navigation {
  background: #161616;
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-end;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.menuNav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 250px;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* shout out to Andrea Tondo for the incredible drop down effect sans JS ===> https://codepen.io/Tont/
Style for the first level menu bar*/
ul#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #eee;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

ul#menu > li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 18px 0 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/*hide the inputs*/
input {
  display: none;
}

/*show the second level menu of the selected voice*/
input:checked ~ div.submenu {
  max-height: 100vh;
  transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in;
}

/*style for the second level menu*/
.submenu {
  height: 100vh;
}

div.submenu {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
}

div.submenu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) inset;
  transition: background .3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes delay {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="about">
      <input id="check01" type="radio" name="menu" />
      <label for="check01">ABOUT</label>
      <div class="submenu">
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel nam, autem eligendi tempora non dicta ullam! Deserunt similique cum et impedit dolorem dignissimos necessitatibus ducimus, fuga beatae nemo ipsam quidem.</div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <input id="check02" type="radio" name="menu" />
      <label for="check02">LINK</label>
      <div class="submenu">
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel nam, autem eligendi tempora non dicta ullam! Deserunt similique cum et impedit dolorem dignissimos necessitatibus ducimus, fuga beatae nemo ipsam quidem.</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there in your codepen, your sub-menu was already utilising `position: absolute;`, which then just needed a `left:0;`.

The above fix however was hindered by the `position:relative;` on your menu `li` elements. Once you removed these, it works perfectly.

Here's an [adjusted version of your codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLZjpz), the code I changed was:

```
ul#menu > li{
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
  /*position: relative;*/
}
```

and

```
div.submenu{
  max-height:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
  transition:max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
  left: 0; /*this was added*/
}
```

Here's a full working example:

```css
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section,summary{display:block;}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}[hidden]{display:none;}html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}a:focus{outline:thin dotted;}a:active,a:hover{outline:0;}h1{font-size:2em;}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}b,strong{font-weight:700;}dfn{font-style:italic;}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000;}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace, serif;font-size:1em;}pre{white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}q{quotes:\201C \201D \2018 \2019;}small{font-size:80%;}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline;}sup{top:-.5em;}sub{bottom:-.25em;}img{border:0;}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden;}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}button,input{line-height:normal;}button,html input[type=button],/* 1 */
input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}body,figure{margin:0;}legend,button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}

.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }

* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }


*{margin:0; padding:0;
}

header,
footer, 
section {
   overflow: hidden;
}


html{
 font-size: 62.5%;
}

body{
 font-size: 1.6rem;
}


img{
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
}


a{
 text-decoration: none;
}



/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/




/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/


header{
 /*     background-color: blue;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 2000px; 
}

.navigation{
 background: #161616;
 height: 10vh;
 display: flex;
 align-content: flex-end;
 color: white;
}

a{
 color: white;
}

.menuNav{
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-end; 
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: 250px;
 color: white;
 list-style-type: none;
}




/* shout out to Andrea Tondo for the incredible drop down effect sans JS ===> https://codepen.io/Tont/

Style for the first level menu bar*/
ul#menu{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 10vh;
  margin:0;
  color:#eee;

}

ul{
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-end;
}

ul#menu > li{
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
}

label{
  position:relative;
  padding:0 18px 0 12px;
  cursor:pointer;


}

label:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:50%;
  right:5px;
  width:0;
  height:0;


  }

/*hide the inputs*/
input{display:none}

/*show the second level menu of the selected voice*/
input:checked ~ div.submenu{
  max-height:100vh;
  transition:max-height 0.8s ease-in;
}

/*style for the second level menu*/

.submenu{
 height: 100vh;

}

div.submenu{
  max-height:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
  transition:max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
  left: 0;
}


div.submenu li a{
  display:block;
  padding:12px;
  color:#ddd;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow:0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,.5) inset;
  transition:background .3s;
  white-space:nowrap;
}


  @keyframes delay{
    0%{opacity: 0;}
    60%{opacity: 0;}
    99%{opacity: 0;}
    100%{opacity:1;}
  }*/
```

```html
<div class="navigation">

   <ul id="menu">
      <li class="about">
         <input id="check01" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
         <label for="check01">ABOUT</label>
           <div class="submenu">
             <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel nam, autem eligendi tempora non dicta ullam! Deserunt similique cum et impedit dolorem dignissimos necessitatibus ducimus, fuga beatae nemo ipsam quidem.</div>
           </div> 
         </li>

          <li class="LINK">
         <input id="check02" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
         <label for="check02">LINK</label>
           <div class="submenu">
             <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel nam, autem eligendi tempora non dicta ullam! Deserunt similique cum et impedit dolorem dignissimos necessitatibus ducimus, fuga beatae nemo ipsam quidem.</div>
           </div> 
         </li>



      </ul>

     </div>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks so much. Also updated it to use radio buttons rather than checkboxes to give a closing effect before the next menu opens.

Comment: @maxineheadroom Awesome nicely done :) It's a super interesting way of doing a menu, I must admit. Am I right in assuming that you are using `li:checked` as a part of your property selector?

Comment: the way I have it currently is input:checked. would li:checked be better practice or have an advantage I may not be aware of (I'm not aware of a lot tbh)

Comment: No no no `li:checked` is invalid (typo from my side I'm afraid - *blushes* sorry!). `input:checked` is indeed the best way to go about it :)